# May I adjust the placement of the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am satisfied with the table of contents in my document, but how may I adjust it, say, two centimeters downward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
% tocprob.tex  SE 599888
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% move ToC title down by 2cm
\addtolength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

There are also lengths `\cftbeforeloftitleskip` and `\cftbeforelottitleskip` for adjusting the space above the LoF and LoT titles. The package provides many commands for changing the formatting of the ToC etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using the setspace package and increase the line spacing by writing

\begin{spacing}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}